# Is it possible to limit SSH access for certain users based on schedule?

Tags: ssh, scheduling

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to limit SSH access to certain users, so that they can connect only during a certain time period.

Let's say, username "A" can access SSH only during office hours, username "B" can access SSH only after office hours, etc.

Comment: Not sure, but changing their login shell to a custom script might work. It will either `exec sh` at the end, or if it is the wrong time, `exec false`.

Comment: @Bobby hmm... I suspected such... still hoping for a less 'hackish' method though... but thanks for reminding.

Comment: [In that case you might want to look into this](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/227/Restricting_server_access_by_time).

Comment: @Bobby - That links seems simple and good. But unfortunately that method is not working for me.

Comment: A reasonable question, before suggesting an answer, is: what do you wish to do with those users who legged in before the curfew, but who are still there after curfew begins?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae well, I wish I could maintain their connection, but if it is too complex to do so, an abrupt abort is acceptable.

Comment: @Bobby ahhh, thanks! That looks like what I need... I'll study more on pam conf's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I believe those users are in your local network and are having static ip addresses. If yes, then we can create a cron to change the /etc/hosts.deny file during regular intervals. For eg:

The /etc/hosts.deny will be blank during the allowed hours and it must change to the following during the restricted hours

> sshd: ALL EXCEPT `<specify ips of users here>`

I hope you understood my point.

Comment: Point understood, sir. Unfortunately, the IP addresses of the users are DHCP based, so I think this solution is not suitable for me...